# Unsubscribe does not work on RXJS, what is the correct method of use?

Tags: angular, rxjs, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I made a code to monitor a map using *nativescript-geolocation* and *nativescript-google-maps-sdk*, there is an Angular service that encapsulates all access logic to *nativescript-geolocation* that receives a subscribe provided by a comment from Angular.

When executing the listener represented by the `component.mapViewRead()` function, which runs when the map is ready, it subscribes to the subscribe service by calling a method `servico.gpsInfo$.subscribe((gpsInfo) => this.gpsInfo = gpsInfo)`, when the user manipulates the map by changing the camera position to a new coordinate, a property representing *subscripition* is used by another listener responsible for manipulating the camera to disable subscribe by calling the `this.subscription.unsubscribe()`.

Although the subscription is theoretically disabled and can be entered through the `this.subscription.isClosed` property, it does not stop processing Observable calls.

Am I doing something wrong? or is it a RXJS bug?

Below is the code for both service and component.

[At this link](https://github.com/islamic-works/mussala-module/blob/master/compass.service.ts) you can find the full code of the service, and below the code relevant to the problem.

```
startHeadingUpdates() {
        if (this.watchId) {
            return;
        }

        this.watchId = geoLocation.watchLocation(
            (loc) => {
                if (loc) {
this._gpsInfo.next(<GPSInfo>loc);
                }
            },
            (e) => {
                console.error("Error: " + e.message);
            },
            { desiredAccuracy: 3, updateDistance: 10, minimumUpdateTime: 1000 * .3 });
    }
    public get gpsInfo(): Observable<GPSInfo> {
        if (!this._gpsInfo$)
            this._gpsInfo$ = this._gpsInfo.asObservable()
        return this._gpsInfo$;
    }
```

Full component code can be found [at this link](https://github.com/islamic-works/mussala-module/blob/master/mussala-maps/mussala-maps.components.ts), below only the code relevant to the problem:

```
// componente
    private subscribeGPSInfo() {
        if(this._gpsInfoSubscription && !this._gpsInfoSubscription.isClosed)
            this.unSubscribegpsInfo();

       this._gpsInfoSubscription = this._compass.gpsInfo.subscribe((gpsInfo) => {
            this.gpsInfo = gpsInfo;
        }, (error) => {         console.error("MussalaMapsComponent.ngAfterViewInit() _compass.gpsInfo.subscribe ", error);
        });
    }

    private unsubscribeGPSInfo() {
        if (this._gpsInfoSubscription && this._gpsInfoSubscription.closed) {
        this._gpsInfoSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    goToMyLocation() {
        const cfg: GPSConfig = {};
        this._compass.getMyLocation(cfg)
            .then((gpsInfo: GPSInfo) => {
                this.gpsInfo = gpsInfo;
                this.mapView.latitude = this.gpsInfo.latitude;
                this.mapView.longitude = this.gpsInfo.longitude;
            });

        this.subscribeGPSInfo();
    }
    onMapReady(event) {
        const template = this.createInfoWindowTemplate();
        this.mapView.infoWindowTemplates = template;

        let marker: Marker = this._compass.createIslamicMarker(
            1,
            MakerType.MUSSALA,
            "Mussala Fortaleza",
            "Fortaleza, Ce, Brasil",
            "Rua São Paulo, 1831 - Jacarecanga, Fortaleza - CE, 60310-226",
            //-3.7214696,-38.5430259
            <GPSInfo>{ latitude: -3.7214696, longitude: -38.5430259 }
        );
        this.mapView.addMarker(marker);

        marker = this._compass.createIslamicMarker(
            2,
            MakerType.SPONSOR,
            "Curso Arduino Minas",
            "Aquiraz, Ce, Brasil",
            "R. José Alves Pereira, S/N, Aquiraz, CE, Brasil",
            {
                latitude: -3.9242100850690402,
                longitude: -38.45365650951862
            }
        );

        this.mapView.addMarker(marker);

        this.goToMyLocation();
        this.subscribeGPSInfo();

        this.isBusy = false;

    }
```

**More Info:**

```
 npm list rxjs
IslamicApp@ C:\Users\Admin\workspace\islamic-works\Islamic-App
+-- @angular/cli@8.1.1
| +-- @angular-devkit/architect@0.801.1
| | `-- rxjs@6.4.0
| +-- @angular-devkit/core@8.1.1
| | `-- rxjs@6.4.0
| +-- @angular-devkit/schematics@8.1.1
| | `-- rxjs@6.4.0
| +-- @schematics/update@0.801.1
| | `-- rxjs@6.4.0
| `-- inquirer@6.4.1
|   `-- rxjs@6.5.2  deduped
+-- @nativescript/schematics@0.6.0
| +-- @angular-devkit/core@7.1.4
| | `-- rxjs@6.3.3
| `-- @angular-devkit/schematics@7.1.4
|   `-- rxjs@6.3.3  deduped
+-- @ngtools/webpack@8.0.6
| +-- @angular-devkit/core@8.0.6
| | `-- rxjs@6.4.0  deduped
| `-- rxjs@6.4.0
+-- nativescript-dev-webpack@1.0.1
| `-- @angular-devkit/core@8.0.0
|   `-- rxjs@6.4.0
`-- rxjs@6.5.2
```

Comment: I'm not certain but looking at the code you seem to call `subscribeGPSInfo()` from 2 different places, still you are not checking whether it was already subscribed. So it might be possible you are having multiple subscriptions and unsubscribing only the last subscription.

Comment: I checked the code for only one active subscriber at a time. And every time I run unsubscribe it's registered as "closed"

Answer (score -1):

I went to your Github link (now dead) to try and run the app to diagnose but it is not an app. It is a code snippet. Can you setup a small example app? This will help you faster.

In the meantime, it seems you are trying to unsubscribe from `this._gpsInfoSubscription` which is a **result** of `this._compass.gpsInfo.subscribe(...)`.

I would suggest you take a look at `NetanelBasal/ngx-take-until-destroy`. Using rxjs `pipe` with `ngx-take-until-destroy`will help memory clean up more efficiently. I use it daily in my Angular applications.

Comment: Thomas the code is so dirty and with lots of unnecessary packages, but I'll zip it and put it in git, just a moment.

Comment: In addition there is still sensitive data that I will not be able to move now.

Comment: It seems to me that the best solution is to check if the subscriber is closed through your subscription, so it doesn't execute. nx does not seem to me to be the solution as nothing is destroyed during this process. It's just a temporary interruption of the listener, I think a flag will be more appropriate.